# how is this ranked-choice election being decided/tabulated?

Tags: discussion

i have to admit i was a little surprized to see that it was ranked choice.  that's a good move.

is it decided using Single-Transferable Vote (STV) which is often called Instant Runoff Voting (IRV) when there is a single winner?

or is it Condorcet?

i surely hope not Borda count.  that's the worst way to do a ranked-choice election.

Comment: okay, i have to read things a little.  i know a bit about voting methods but never heard about the particular ["Meek STV"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_single_transferable_votes#Meek.27s_method).  took a quick look at it and still haven't groked it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an instant runoff. Those tend to work best when there is [just one open position](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/1479/132). You can read more about the system we use in [How are moderator election votes counted, in plain English?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english) But I will warn you, I didn't fully understand myself until I worked through the process using data from an acutal election.

In the [current election](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/election/1) with 4 candidate vying for 3 moderator slots, the method is very likely to eliminate whoever shows up on the fewest ballots. That matches our common sense about how elections should work, I believe.

Comment: it's funny, i have participated in a lot of electoral activities, (i happen to be an Inspector of Election in Ward 7 of Burlington VT and got to shake Bernie's and Jane's hands right after they cast their primary votes) and i participate in this [Election Methods mailing list](http://lists.electorama.com/listinfo.cgi/election-methods-electorama.com).  we talk about STV and other methods a lot.  both single-winner and multi-winner.  we have never, in my recollection, discussed [Meek STV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_single_transferable_votes#Meek).  how was that method chosen?

Comment: BTW, **any** STV is a form of Instant Runoff.  every time V's are T'ed, it's a runoff and it happens as instantly as computer can execute the code.

Comment: and like all other STV's (except *STV-BTR* where *"BTR"* means "bottom-two runoff"), this method is **opaque** to one's second choice when it comes to elimination of *"whoever shows up on the fewest ballots"*.  you mean *"whoever is ranked **highest** on the fewest ballots"*.  doesn't matter that everyone likes this person 2nd, if such a candidate does not get enough first-choice votes, that candidate will be eliminated and all of the second-choice votes cast for that candidate will count for naught.  this is why most election scholars hate STV or IRV and prefer Condorcet.